# How to debug Matlab engine C API?

Tags: c, matlab

The engine API allows use call MATLAB from C

http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/calling-matlab-engine-from-c-c-and-fortran-programs.html

What is the best practice to debug the interface? Can we somehow 'open' the MATLAB session created by the APIs in MATLAB IDE and debug MATLAB code we send to the session by the APIS?

I can print out the MATLAB code status into a log file for debugging, but this is not efficient.

Comment: I would make sure the MATLAB side works (unit tests with expected inputs); that can be done entirely in MATLAB. For the C end, make sure that inputs to MATLAB API are only what's expected.

Comment: @zeeMonkeez This is a compositional solution, although being able to debug via connect C and Matlab together would be more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

The idiot solution would be to just open gdb/visual studio and attach to the running Matlab process. If you're lucky Matlab just loads your code without changes and then you can put breakpoints in your code as you would with any other program.

I've done this previously with other programs (not matlab) in visual studio and it amazes me how often it works.

Comment: Will this allow us to debug Matlab scripts? I think gdb can only debug C code, but not the scripts we send to Matlab by engineEvalString.

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear from your question what you wanted to do. If you just want to debug matlab code, why not just use the standard matlab debugger?

Comment: In linux, C engine API creates a different matlab session. I am not sure how to find or open that session in Matlab debugger.

Comment: Can't you output the generated code to a file and run it manually? It seems like very hard work to write a code generator without inspecting the generated code somehow.